# Python regular expression ".+" vs ".*"

Tags: regex, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, when i try re.findall("abc.","abcd abc"), I receive the expected answer "abcd" only

if I use re.findall("abc.asterisk*","abcd abc") I receive "abcd" "abc" as expected
but when I use re.findall('abc.+',"abcd abc") I receive "abcd" "abc" again instead of just "abcd"

Why?

Comment: Visit an [explainer site](https://regex101.com). This is really fundamental to how a regular expression works. `+` means "one or more" while `*` means "zero or more".

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking but `.*` will match between 0 and unlimited of any character (except new line) and `.+` will match between ` and unlimited of the same character set.

Comment: You don't receive "abcd" and "abc" but the unique whole string "abcd abc".

Comment: @tadman that's is correct, it's not the same as "exactly one match", you're right

Answer (score 0):

As the comments says, * is for 0 or more matches, + is for 1 or more matches.

If you want exactly 1 match, you shuld do directly like:

```
abc.
```

Comment: If you want exactly one match, just use `.`; no need to add any repeat constructs.

Comment: @DanielH MMM, that's true, I will change